# Nextjs Vercel Deployment error only - Application error: a client-side exception

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel, trpc

On localhost the application runs flawlessly but on production I'm getting this error when doing a post request on a trpc end point.

`Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).`

This is what is inside the console.
[image]

I've spent time trying to understand trpc error handling but haven't had any success

Thank you

EDIT: For anyone else coming across this - there were multiple issues with this:

1. The type used in catch block was incorrect.
2. Vercel deployment defaults to 10 second timeouts whereas my api request was taking more time.
3. I was trying to infer json from the text as I didn't account for the timeouts.

Hope that helps